# Python speed testing -- why does an except failure cost so much time

Tags: python

I assumed a try / except workflow would be faster than an if / then workflow for the simple action 'try to remove x from list_l'. In the below example, the except failures (x not in list_l) cost more times than permission requests (if x is in list_l) even though there chance of an exception is 16.6% of the time. Why?

Here are the tests I coded and their results:

```
import random, time, timeit

class Timer(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.secs = self.end - self.start
        self.msecs = self.secs * 1000  # millisecs

def a_function():
    a_list = list(xrange(10))
    choice_list = list(xrange(12))
    choice = random.choice(choice_list)
    try:
        a_list.remove(choice)

    except ValueError:
        pass

def b_function():
    a_list = list(xrange(10))
    choice_list = list(xrange(12))
    choice = random.choice(choice_list)
    if choice in a_list:
        a_list.remove(choice)

with Timer() as a:
    print('test_a', timeit.timeit("a_function()", number=10000, setup="from __main__ import a_function"))

with Timer() as b:
    print('test_b', timeit.timeit("b_function()", number=10000, setup="from __main__ import b_function"))
```

The results:

`1st attempt: ('test_a', 0.029724836349487305)('test_b', 0.027068138122558594)`

`2nd attempt: ('test_a', 0.02960801124572754)('test_b', 0.026785850524902344)`

`3rd attempt: ('test_a', 0.029654979705810547)('test_b', 0.02665996551513672)`

Also, if I increase the choice_list range to 20, the difference widens because exceptions occur more frequently. If python is strongly ask-forgiveness-not-permission, why does failure seem to cost some much in terms of time?

Comment: Try/catch by necessity must include the same construct (a conditional jump) as an if/then.  Since it has to deal with more things (like returning to you what the error was), try/catch will necessarily be slower than you doing the test yourself.

Comment: What does that `Timer` context manager do? It appears to be dead code, and you're already suing `timeit` as you should.

Comment: @delnan the Timer thing might be cruft from when I first started speed testing code. All I usually do is simply code the functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exceptions are very expensive in any language, and this is a misuse of them.

Exceptions are meant for *exceptional* circumstances that your code cannot account for and that are not expected to come up during normal operations. Different languages have different rules for what is exceptional, but something that happens 16% of the time is not exceptional, just unusual.

Exceptions are expensive because they involve a stack unwind and a jump, pausing of normal processing, and a search for a handler. If/then is a standard, normal conditional that is efficient and clear.

Comment: While I agree with you in principle, in Python, users are strongly encouraged to use the `try...except` construct in many cases where other languages would employ an `if...then` clause. While it is not computationally efficient, it is semantically efficient (in Python) to use exceptions to pass certain types of messages up the call stack. This is especially true because of the "duck-typing" paradigm encouraged in Python.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Interesting. I don't know much Python (I'm a Ruby guy). In Ruby we have a special exception-like construct for this, which is actually named throw and catch. Exceptions are reserved for the truly exceptional (another example of that is Obj-C).

Comment: Interesting background then: http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/

Comment: In this case, I think you're right though. Clearly, the OP is interested in efficiency, and additionally `try...except` doesn't seem to be contributing anything useful to the semantics of the code in the OP's examples.

Comment: @doctorlove: That is interesting. Thanks!

Comment: What @JoelCornett talks about is called the "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" (EAFP) mentality. It is in contrast to LBYL (Look Before You Leap.)

Comment: @kqr: Which is basically C, Obj-C, etc. errors vs. Ruby/Python/etc. errors.

Comment: @doctorlove's link gets some details wrong... for example, when iterating over a list, there's no `StopIteration` raised; lists don't have an `__iter__()` method, so the `for` statement keeps an index into the list, increments it on each pass, and stops when it gets `IndexError`.

Comment: @kindall: OK then. That makes more sense to me. Are you sure it isn't a Python 2 vs Python 3 thing?

Comment: @doctorlove: Agreed, especially since the general gist is correct (an exception is in fact used to terminate a `for` loop), it's just that it is sometimes not `StopIteration`. I did add a comment over there about why not to use bare `except:` as well.

Comment: @doctorlove the linked article was great. Exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This is a total stab in the dark but it could be due to exception handling being class based and if/then being purely logic based. So the interpreter can optimize simple conditional handing far more than it can class flows.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-352.html

Comment: CPython does no such optimizations.